# Como fazer pra esconder ou limpar a url ao dar um get em asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, rotas

Queria saber como faço para limpar ou esconder dados que passo por uma URL pra uma webapi de forma a os dados n ficarem aparentes e não atrapalharem minhas rotas..

segue exemplo:
`http://localhost:65286/Cliente/Login?Email=alguem%40gmail.com&Password=123123123`

```
       public IActionResult Login(string Email, string Password)
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, BaseUrlFuncionario + "/Login/"+ Email +"/"+ Password);

        HttpResponseMessage response = HttpInstance.GetHttpClientInstance().SendAsync(request).Result;

        Funcionario funcionario = new Funcionario();

        string l = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        funcionario = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Funcionario>(l);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            TempData["Funcionario"] = funcionario;
            return View("Principal", TempData);
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Pelo o que você escreveu , você está fazendo requisições 'GET'  para validação de login. Tem  como publicar seu código que faz a chamada na API?

Comment: editei a pergunta inserindo o meu método

Comment: a API é sua, você pode alterar o código dela?
você teria que usar assim : `new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, BaseUrlFuncionario + "/Login/"+ Email +"/"+ Password);`.

Porém sua api tem que estar preparada pra receber requisição POST  e não GET

Comment: Valeu, mudei tudo para post e funcionou!!!

Comment: Se tudo funcionou, marque como respondida, ajudará os próximos que visualizarem a questão

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Troque o método de GET para POST e acredito que resolverá o seu problema